# How best to pray shaḥarit and musaf separately

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, musaf

Say that you are unable to pray with a *minyan*, and it is a day on which *musaf* is said.  You plan on praying everything up to and including *shaḥarit* in one go, and then pray *musaf* later (since [*musaf* need not be said at the same time as *shaḥarit*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&rtype=%u05D8%u05E2%u05E7%u05E1%u05D8%20-%20%u05E4%u05E8%u05D9%u05D9%u05D3%u05D1%u05E8%u05D2&hilchos=7&perek=3&halocha=5)).  What do you do about everything that comes after *shaḥarit* besides the *musaf* prayer itself?

I see two main possibilities:

1. You should not deviate from the usual order of the prayer service. You should stop at some point (**where?**) after *shaḥarit*, and continue from that point (without repeating anything) when about to pray *musaf*.  Motivation for this choice: this is how the service "normally goes".
2. You should finish the prayer service as you would normally do, omitting *musaf*, and pray *musaf* (and only *musaf*) later. Motivation for this choice: most of the post-*shaḥarit* elements are also said on a day without *musaf*, so why should we omit them now?

Or perhaps some middle ground, where you still finish the service (whatever that means), but omit more than just *musaf* (say, *ein keloheinu* on *shabbat*, or *hosha'not* on *sukkot*), or perhaps where you repeat certain sections when praying *musaf* (eg. say *ashrei* again).

Does the answer change depending on how long the gap is between *shaḥarit* and *musaf*? Does the answer change depending on what the day is (*shabbat*, *yom tov*, *rosh ḥodesh*, *ḥol hammo'ed*)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: @donielf for instance, when would you say Uva leTzion? When would you say Alenu? Shir shel Yom? Hallel? Yekum Purkan? Etc.

Comment: The most reasonable thing to say twice is Alenu, like saying Alenu after Mincha when prayed separately from Maariv.